# the execution is not stopping at break point in robot file in visual studio code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, robotframework, breakpoints

I want to run .robot file  with breakpoint in visual studio code .
I installed visual studio code , added extensions below and created .robot file and then provided break point at code.
But when i do debugging
Run->Start debugging =>the execution is not stopping at break point.The ececution is going through complete code and generating reports.It is not stopping at break point.

the softwares =>
Operating System -windows10

Python -3.8

Robot framework-3.1.1

In visual studio code the extensions added are
Robot framework intellisence -2.8.0

Robot framework debugger -1.4.3

Python for VSCCode -0.2.3

Can some one help how to stop execution at breakpoint in robot file